# regex string of 0 or 8 chars

Tags: regex

How can I write a regular expression that would accept only alphanumeric chars and the string's length be 0 or 8?
What i managed to do until now is

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0-8}$
```

Which verifies that my string contains only alphanumeric chars but still allows any string of length between 0 and 8. Is there any way to separate it in either {0} || {8} (in same regex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: did you want to allow `foobarba`? since it contains alphabetic characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}|)$
```

Try this for only `0` or `8`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/9

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was needing. I will accept the answer in 10 mins (when I will be allowed)

Comment: or `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{8})?$`

Comment: there's no need for `?:` operator if you use the anchors.  Just `^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8}|)$` or `^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})?$`